# The code is showing a error that "ledpin2 is not declared in the scope"

Tags: compilation-errors

```
int ledPin1 = 1;
int ledpin2 = 2;
int ledpin3 = 3;
int ledpin4 = 4;
int ledpin5 = 5;
int ledpin6 = 6;

void setup()
{
  //initialize pins as outputs
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledpin6, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin5, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledpin5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpin4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPin5, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
  delay(200);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a typo.

Answer (score 4):

You mix capitals with non capital characters.

The case of characters in variable names are important, so ledPin2 is a different variable than ledpin2.

Also, never mix similar names (unless it is trivial). Either always use ledpinx or ledPinx, not sometimes the first and sometimes the second version.

camelCasing is normally used for local variables, means the first sub-word starts with a lower case, rest with upper case, thus led-pin will become ledPin.

Pascal case is the other way: that would become LedPin in your case.

For global variables I tend to use PascalCasing, or if it is within one file, prefixed camelCasing with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your code it was just because you mixed capital and lowercase letters while declaring `ledPin`. Keep it same everywhere in `setup()` and `loop()`.

```cpp
int ledPin1 = 1;
int ledPin2 = 2;
int ledPin3 = 3;
int ledPin4 = 4;
int ledPin5 = 5;
int ledPin6 = 6;

void setup()
{
    //initialize pins as outputs
    pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin6, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin5, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin5, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin5, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
    delay(200);
}
```